# how to rotate multiple cookies with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, rotation, ads

`hello please i am new to selenium, i need help in writing a code that can rotate proxy, rotate user agent and and rotate cookies and then click on ads but it is giving me hard time can anyone help please, the bot currently randomly select the links from list of links.csv but does not get to the cookies and user agent

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
import csv
import json

# Load the user agents from useragent.csv
useragents = []
with open('useragent.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        useragents.append(row[0])

# Load the cookies from cookie.json
with open('cookie.json', 'r') as file:
    cookies = json.load(file)

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

# Set a random user agent
user_agent = random.choice(useragents)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Visit google.com
driver.get('https://google.com')

# Set the cookies
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

# Send random keys from links.csv
with open('links.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    links = list(reader)

random_link = random.choice(links)
search_input = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_input.send_keys(random_link[0])
search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Click on the first Google result
first_result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#search div.g:nth-child(1) a')
first_result.click()

# Mouse hover to the first post
first_post = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.post:nth-child(1)')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(first_post)
hover.perform()

# Scroll down slowly
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3)

# Click on the first post
first_post.click()

# Wait for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)

# Go back one page
driver.back()

# Mouse hover over to the second post
second_post = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.post:nth-child(2)')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(second_post)
hover.perform()

# Scroll down slowly
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3)

# Click on the second post
second_post.click()

# Wait for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)

# Click on Related Articles or related post
related_articles = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.related-articles')
related_articles.click()

# Wait until popup appears and click on the popup
popup = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.popup')
if popup.is_displayed():
    popup.click()
else:
    pass

# Repeat the process for 5 times
for _ in range(5):
    # Perform the actions again
    # ...
    pass

# Stop the process
driver.quit()
```

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it in console/terminal? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.